# Getting .NET Intergation Services working on Second Instance of ColdFusion 10

Tags: .net, coldfusion

I'm running CF 10 Enterprise, with .NET integration services installed after the initial installation and configuration of the two instances. The instance names are "cfusion", the default, and we'll call the second one "instance2".

I installed .NET Integration Services through the standalone installer and chose c:\ColdFusion10\cfusion as the directory that it should install to. It created the jnbridge directory in the cfusion instance, and created the ColdFusion10DotNetService directoy. Running the following code under the fusion instance works perfectly:

```
<cfset UtilitiesProxy = "c:/inetpub/CFCs/MyCo/Integration/UtilitiesProxy.jar" />
<cfset CoStarUtilities = "c:/inetpub/CFCs/MyCo/Integration/MyCo.Utilities.dll" />
<cfset Paths = ArrayToList([CoStarUtilities, UtilitiesProxy]) />

<cfset Publisher = CreateObject( ".net", "MyCo.Utilities.Wall.Publisher", Paths ).init() />
```

Running the same code under `instance2` gives me an error that `The assembly that contains the class must be provided to the assembly attribute.` This is the same error that I received before I got the .NET integration services working correctly under cfusion.

So what I need to find out is how to allow `instance2` access to the .NET integration services. I've tried copying over the jnbridge directory to `c:\ColdFusion10\instance2` and restarting the instance, but that didn't correct the problem. I'm under the impression that I'm missing some other piece of the puzzle since `instance2` was created before the .NET Integration Services were installed.

Comment: Can't you just run the standalone installer again but choose the other instance's directory?

Comment: I don't usually make a habit of running an installer twice for something that should be a one-time deal. However, I did it, and it appears to be working. .NET is responding on both instances at the moment. I'm going to restart both of them this evening and ensure they continue to work. Post this as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted a soon as I verify that both servers work correctly after a full restart. Thanks Miguel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention that you ran the installer and specified your first ColdFusion instance as the source folder I would try running the installer again and specifying the second ColdFusion instance as the source folder.  I'm sure that the installer is doing more than simply copying files (probably adding registry entries, etc.).  So running it against the second instance's folder might get things going for you.